# How to do mongoDB migration when model was a concrete type and now is an interface

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB C# driver version 2.4.4.

I am having problems migrating old documents that were based in a concrete type to a new model, that is based on interface.

At the beginning the model was something like:

```
public class DeliveryRoute : MongoDbItem
{
    ...
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now, I needed to chance to an interface, and new code looks like:

```
public class DeliveryRoute : MongoDbItem
{
    ...
    public List<IStep> Steps { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When I save new documents, MongoDB Driver saves a field named "_t" that contains the concrete type.

[image]

The problems is that I already have some documents that don't have this field.
I thought that solution was easy, then I created this script to add the new field for every collection that I have:

```
db.getCollection('MongoDBDeliveryRouteCollection').find({"UnitCode":"016302", "_id":"01630220181030013818"})
.forEach(function(deliveryRouteDocument){

        deliveryRouteDocument.Steps.forEach(function(step){

              if(!step.hasOwnProperty('_t')){
                  step._t = "Step";
              }
        });
       db.getCollection('MongoDBDeliveryRouteCollection').save(deliveryRouteDocument);
    })
```

The field was created.

But seems that the driver is ignoring the "_t" when it is created by the script.
Resulting in the error:

> Unable to determine actual type of object to deserialize for interface
>   type PathTracker.Common.Interfaces.IStep.

Somebody has some idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687139/2982747) question is the same as yours? It is possible to register a serializer for your interface type via `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer`. That way the driver understands what class you wish to use underlying. this could solve the error `Unable to determine actual type of object to deserialize for interface type`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36431600/2982747) answer to another question could be a solution as well.